# I want to decrypt the url of video which i scrap

Tags: python, json, url, python-requests, youtube

I made this code to extract the final link of YouTube video but this is encrypted in signatureCipher i don't know how to decrypt this to get file size from this url's headers response.

```
import requests

import json

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgzLnmTaCAU'

r = requests.get(url)

if r.status_code == 200:

    start = r.text.find('ytInitialPlayerResponse') + len('ytInitialPlayerResponse') + 3

    end = r.text.find('};', start) + 1

    json_str = r.text[start:end]

    data = json.loads(json_str)

    streaming_data = data['streamingData']

    formats = streaming_data['formats'][0]

    cipher = formats['signatureCipher']

    video_url = cipher.split('=')[3]

    print(video_url)
```

I already made one more script which was doing well but suddenly it stopped working for particular below url which i used in above script to solve the signatureCipher problem

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgzLnmTaCAU'

Below is the that script which is working good like what i want! But not working for this url

```
import requests

import json

#url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDmfFdAfytM'

url = "https://youtu.be/RgzLnmTaCAU"

r = requests.get(url)

if r.status_code == 200:

    start = r.text.find('ytInitialPlayerResponse') + len('ytInitialPlayerResponse') + 3

    end = r.text.find('};', start) + 1

    json_str = r.text[start:end]

    data = json.loads(json_str)

    streaming_data = data['streamingData']

    formats = streaming_data['formats']

    adaptive_formats = streaming_data['adaptiveFormats']

    print("================ Formats =================")

    format_labels = {}

    format_count = 1

    for video_data in formats:

        quality_label = video_data['qualityLabel']

        format_labels[format_count] = quality_label

        print(format_count, ": ", quality_label)

        format_count += 1

    print("================ Adaptive Formats =================")

    for adaptive_video_data in adaptive_formats:

        if 'qualityLabel' in adaptive_video_data:

            quality_label = adaptive_video_data['qualityLabel']

            format_labels[format_count] = quality_label

            print(format_count, ": ", quality_label)

            format_count += 1

        

    selected_format = int(input("\nEnter the number corresponding to the quality label you want to view: "))

    

    if selected_format in format_labels:

        selected_quality_label = format_labels[selected_format]

        print("\nSelected Quality Label: ", selected_quality_label)

        print("\nVideo Data for Selected Quality Label:\n")

        

        for video_data in formats:

            if video_data['qualityLabel'] == selected_quality_label:

                itag = video_data['itag']

                url = video_data['url']

                height = video_data['height']

                width = video_data['width']

                quality = video_data['quality']

                quality_label = video_data['qualityLabel']

                audio_quality = video_data['audioQuality']

                bitrate_mbps = round(video_data['bitrate'] / (1024 * 1024), 2)

                print("itag:", itag)

                print('URL:', url)

                print('Height:', height)

                print('Width:', width)

                print('Quality:', quality)

                print('Bitrate:', quality_label, f'({bitrate_mbps} Mbps)')

                print('Audio Quality:', audio_quality)

                size = requests.get(url, stream=True)

                file_size = size.headers['content-length'] or size.headers['Content-Length']

                print(f'File Size:, {int(file_size)/1024/1024:.3f} MB')

                print("\n")

        for adaptive_video_data in adaptive_formats:

            if 'qualityLabel' in adaptive_video_data and adaptive_video_data['qualityLabel'] == selected_quality_label:

                itag = adaptive_video_data['itag']

                url = adaptive_video_data['url']

                height = adaptive_video_data['height']

                width = adaptive_video_data['width']

                quality = adaptive_video_data['quality']

                quality_label = adaptive_video_data['qualityLabel']

                bitrate_mbps = round(adaptive_video_data['bitrate'] / (1024 * 1024), 2)

                print("itag:", itag)

                print('URL:', url)

                print('Height:', height)

                print('Width:', width)

                print('Quality:', quality)

                print('Bitrate:', quality_label, f'({bitrate_mbps} Mbps)')

                file_lenght = requests.get(url, stream=True)

                size_of_file = file_lenght.headers['content-length'] or file_lenght.headers['Content-Length']

                print(f'File Size:, {int(size_of_file)/1024/1024:.3f} MB')

                print("\n")

    else:

        print("Invalid Selection")

else:

    print('Error: Could not retrieve content from the URL')
```

Please help me to get my desired result.

I am expecting my above script should work like my below script.

Answer (score 0):

*If getting YouTube video downloadable file size is your motto, then you can make it simpler with Pytube module instead struggling with requests and Json. I recommend the same too as you are using python to achieve it.*

**Just below given one-liner is enough.**

```
import pytube
print("Video file size :", pytube.YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgzLnmTaCAU").streams.get_highest_resolution().filesize, "bytes")
```

**To install pytube,**

```
pip install pytube
```